# HAXM emulator Error

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

**How to fix "Failed to sync vcpu reg" and "Failed to sync HAX vcpu context: ?**

```
 >>emulator-x86 @nexus7
emulator: device fd:948

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg

emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context

Error accepting connection, aborting
```